# Not able to delete record even if it is available in the table, [ All conditions are running perfectly except else condition]

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

Here is my code, 
else condition is not executing

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"DELETE FROM Demo_Table WHERE (ID = '"+textBox1.Text+"')",con);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
sda.Fill(dt);

count = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());

if ((textBox1.Text == string.Empty) && (textBox2.Text == string.Empty))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Provide ID and PASSWORD");
    textBox1.Clear();
    textBox2.Clear();
    textBox1.Focus();
}
else if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty)
{
    MessageBox.Show("select ID to delete record");
    textBox2.Clear();
    textBox1.Focus();
}
else if (count == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("wrong ID");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted");
}
```

kindly help.........

Comment: Have you tried the debugger? Does your message box show? What does it say?

Comment: Which else if? The "wrong I'd"?

Comment: All conditions are running properly, except else part,

Comment: i tried to delete existing record but it says that wrong id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, take a look at this example. Comments are in code. Basically, I moved `SQL` command after checking of `textboxes`. Also, because of possible `SQL` injection, added parameters. And, last thing is your usage of data adapter `Fill` method which is why you're getting an error...

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
sda.Fill(dt);
```

this two lines are trying to fill `DataTable` with result of deletion. Since `DataTable` cannot be filled that way, your `count` variable will always be 0.

Instead of `Adapter.Fill` use `ExecuteNonQuery` which will return number of affected rows

```
//first check for user input
if ((textBox1.Text == string.Empty) && (textBox2.Text == string.Empty))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Provide ID and PASSWORD");
    textBox1.Clear();
    textBox2.Clear();
    textBox1.Focus();
    //exit
    return;
}
//then another check
else if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty)
{
    MessageBox.Show("select ID to delete record");
    textBox2.Clear();
    textBox1.Focus();
    //exit from method
    return;
}

//since code went to this line, execute deletion
//no need to use adapter because this command won't fill anything

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"DELETE FROM Demo_Table WHERE (ID = @ID)",con);
//Please use parameters because string concatenation is BAD BAD BAD!
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", int.Parse(textBox1.Text));

//execute query. Count will get number of effected rows (you want it to be 1)
count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

if (count == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("wrong ID");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Record Deleted");
}
```

for SQL injection take a look at [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

Comment: i tryed same code but still getting an error in line sda.Fill(dt)  i states that Must declare the scalar variable "@ID"

Comment: @KalpeshPatil, you shouldn't use `SqlDataAdapter` at all. Copy that large block of code instead of yours and that should do it.

Comment: thanks but still getting error, it shows wrong ID even if it is present in database

Comment: @KalpeshPatil please be more specific; we're all trying to help here. You're getting message that says "wrong ID". Which ID you're entering in textBox? Are you sure that record with that ID exists. Is your ID number or text or...?

Comment: Yes that ID is Exist in DB and it is Number, But when i hit delete button to delete that Existing ID then i get error  "wrong ID"

Comment: @KalpeshPatil Ok, try adding parameter like this `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", int.Parse(textBox1.Text));`. Also, be sure you're using `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` Are you sure you're working with correct database? Check your connection string. I have changed the answer too.

Comment: Boss thank you so much, Finally it's working...Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

ID is a integer or number data type in dB, but your where clause expects it to be alphanumeric.

Try this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"DELETE FROM Demo_Table WHERE ID = 1",con);
```

Pro Tip: ALWAYS use parameterized commands: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0):

I think the count should be the RowsAffected from the query not the number of rows in the grid.

```
count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
//count = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());
```